# How to send a message when a command is not found?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to send a message when a command is not found but it is not working:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print("----------------------")
    print("Logged In As")
    print("Username: %s" % client.user.name)
    print("ID: %s" % client.user.id)
    print("----------------------")
async def on_message(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        text = ('Sorry {}, this command does not exist check $help for a more detailed list of').format(ctx.author.mention)
        msg = await ctx.send(text)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await msg.delete()
    else:
        pass
    raise error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my issue instead of running it through a client.event decorator, I have ran it through a client.listen, decorator:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print("----------------------")
    print("Logged In As")
    print("Username: %s" % client.user.name)
    print("ID: %s" % client.user.id)
    print("----------------------")
@client.listen()
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        text = ('Sorry {}, this command does not exist check $help for a more detailed list of').format(ctx.author.mention)
        msg = await ctx.send(text)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await msg.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `on_command_error` event

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Command does not exist.")
```

Reference:

- [on_command_error](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error)

Comment: I have tried this but I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: and what's the issue?

Comment: I have done the code but when I run a command that doesn't exist it still says command not found even though it is supposed to send a message.

Comment: did you add the decorator `client.event`?

Answer (score 0):

The `on_command_error` event is called when an error happens on **any** command.
and inside the `on_command_error` event you can check whether the error is an instance of `CommandNotFound`, which is thrown when the typed command is not found, or it doesn't exist. And if so, you can send a message to the channel, where the command was used.

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    """Command error handler"""
    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red())
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        embed.title = "Command not Found"
        embed.description = "Recheck what you've typed."
        #await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```